why default copy constructor can copy const or reference member but default copy assign operator can not?
class Test{
    int num;
    const int constVal;
    int& ref;

public:
    Test(int a):constVal(2),ref(a){
        std::cout<<"create"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    int a=23;
    Test tOne(a);
    Test tTwo=tOne;
    return 0;
}

I know if a class have const or reference member,the compiler will not produce the default copy assignment function.Because it is illegal to assign a value to a const or reference object. I wonder why copy constructors work well and I understand that their behavior should be consistent

Because you can initialise const objects and references, but you cannot assign to them. The copy constructor performs initialisation, the assignment operator performs, well, assignment.

So, your question is int a = 23; int& tOne = a; int& tTwo = tOne; - why does it work?

The difference is initialization versus assignment. Just as you can't assign to a constant variable, the automatically generated copy-assignment operator can't assign to a constant member variable.

Basically in C++ assignment and initialisation are two different things and different rules apply. Assignment is changing the value of an existing object, initialisation is (part of) creating a new object namely giving it it's initial value.

Note that reference member variables are unusual.  Not because the language disallows them (they are allowed), but because they are not useful in most situations.

As of c++20, you can workaround the default delete of the copy assignment method by writing a simple custom one. It first destroys the lifetime of the objects then does an in-place construction with the new values.

Const and reference members can't be modified once they're constructed.  But they can be set in the constructor, which is exactly what the default copy constructor does.


why default copy constructor can copy const or reference member but default copy assign operator can not?

Because a constructor performs initialization which happens only once and is allowed for const data member while a assignment operator performs assignment which isn't allowed for const data members.
So the default copy ctor initializes(not assigns) the  const data member which is allowed.
OTOH the copy assignment operator assigns(not initializes) the member which isn't allowed for const member.
